# Using 2 monitors in linux

Tags: graphics-card, display

I've got 740 Radeon with to outs for monitors.
Do you know how can i configure second out to work ?

Comment: I just plugged mine in and it worked, so you're going to need to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problems with a Radeon x1400 in Ubuntu. Finally, I was able to activate the external out with xrandr. In Ubuntu, it can easily be installed if it isn't already.

But as mentioned, you need to give more information:
Which OS? What "outs", vga, dvi ?